# How do create a new file that matches an existing file in Emacs Prelude?

Tags: emacs, emacs-prelude, emacs-helm

In Emacs Prelude, I cannot figure out how to create a new file when a file exists that "matches" the name of the file.

In the example screen capture, I am trying to create a file called `spawn.exs` in a directory that already contains a file called `spawn_basic.exs`. When I use <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd> to create a new file, emacs is matching `spawn.exs` to `spawn_basic.exs` and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> results in opening `spawn_basic.exs` instead of creating `spawn.exs`.

[image]

I've tried some workarounds (i.e. using `touch` to create the file) but I'm looking for a simpler solution that would require only one command. If there is not a command to do this, is there a way to disable the file name matching feature in Prelude? I like most everything else about Prelude compared to vanilla Emacs so I would rather not switch back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Prelude, `C-x C-f` is bound to `helm-find-files`.  It's usually
great, but for this case I don't see a good workaround for bypassing
its match (as you've described).

However, `ido-find-file` has a similarly friendly completion system,
yet offers a nice solution to bypass the completion.  When you type
`spawn.exs`, open by pressing `C-j` instead of `RET`.  I think Helm
should do this too (instead of treating them the same), so you might
want to submit a feature request (to match Ido's "verbatim entry").

Ido works well as a `find-file` replacement, and it's recommended over
Helm for simple cases like this
in [Mastering Emacs](https://www.masteringemacs.org/).  So you could
remap it with:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") 'ido-find-file)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion in the second paragraph and using C-j instead of RET worked! So it appears that helm-find-files does respect C-j for "verbatim entry". Thanks for your answer!